# Абсолютная позиция и прозрачность элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть поле ввода с подсказками (выпадающими вариантами) и кнопка. Работает это всё через чистый JS без jQuery.

По-началу оно работает корректно:

[image: Корректный вариант]

Но после нескольких нажатий, оно становится таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я проверил все z-index и position параметры. Есть мысль, что все дело в opacity. Когда курсор на не элементе, элемент становится немного прозрачным.

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score -1):

Исправил ситуацию. Вынес прозрачность в отдельный css класс. Если подсказки на экране, класс, отвечающий за прозрачность удаляется, иначе добавляется.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вам нужно выложить свой код, чтобы данный пример был полезен другим. Заранее благодарю.